# leiningen install lein-noir failed

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm just starting learning Clojure and web programming. I've installed `Leiningen 2.0.0-preview2` on `Clojure 1.3.0` and it can create projects correctly. But I always got `That's not a task. Use "lein help" to list all tasks.` error when I ran `lein plugin install lein-noir 1.2.1` to install noir.

I've also tried to added lein-noir as a `:dev-dependencies` into `project.clj` and ran `lein deps` but it did nothing.

Does anyone know what's the problem and how can I resolve it. Thanks a lot!

My environment:

- Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Java 6
- Leiningen 2.0.0-preview2

I've also tryed Leiningen 1.7 but got different error and someone said it's because leiningen 1.7 can only work with Clojure 1.2.x
Here's the error when I use Leiningen 1.7:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.(ILclojure/lang/Keyword;)V
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:551)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:426)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:193)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.KeywordLookupSite.(ILclojure/lang/Keyword;)V
    at leiningen.util.plugins$stale_QMARK_.(plugins.clj:68)
    at leiningen.util.plugins__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at leiningen.util.plugins__init.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
    at leiningen.core$loading__4414__auto__.invoke(core.clj:1)
    at leiningen.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at leiningen.core__init.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2030)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:417)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:398)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4610.invoke(core.clj:5386)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5200)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5237)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:602)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5271)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:604)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5363)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at user$eval1.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What kind of error you get with lein 1.7? I think the 2.0.0 version is still too "preview" to use conveniently -- I couldn't get it to work as well. Although I use lein 1.7 with Clojure 1.3 without any problems.

Comment: Leiningen 1.x bundles it's own clojure-1.2 jar that it uses internally, so that won't be a problem. If you post the error you got there, someone might be able to help. I haven't installed leiningen 2 yet though, so I'm not sure what the problem might be there.

Comment: I've modified the question. Can any one have a look again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have added lein-noir to `.lein/profiles.clj` like above you need to run the command :
`lein new noir yoursitename`. 
Not `lein noir new my-website` !

Also add `lein-noir "1.2.1"`

Answer (score 7):

Leiningen 2 is very new. Most of the documentation out there is still describing how to do things with leiningen 1.7.0.  The ways you've tried to install lein-noir don't work with leiningen 2.  The documentation describing how lein version 2 is different from lein 1.7.0 can be found [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Upgrading).

In a nutshell, you need to create a `profiles.clj` file in your `~/.lein` directory. To specify you want to use lein-noir, your ~/.lein/profiles.clj file should look like:

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-noir "1.2.1"]]}}
```

Now you can create a new noir project by typing:

```
lein new noir projectname
```

Comment: Then I got this error: `Could not find artifact lein-noir:lein-noir:pom:1.2.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Retreiving lein-noir/lein-noir/1.2.0/lein-noir-1.2.0.pom (1k)
    from http://clojars.org/repo/
Could not find artifact lein-noir:lein-noir:jar:1.2.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Retreiving lein-noir/lein-noir/1.2.0/lein-noir-1.2.0.jar (6k)
    from http://clojars.org/repo/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)...`

Comment: I incorporated the answer posted by @jasonD.